# DefaultOAuth2ClientContext resets itself after several hours

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, oauth-2.0, tomcat7

I have been using the Spring Sec OAuth2 framework to implement some B2B mechanisms.
Everything works as intended: based on the Authorisation Code i get from my provider, it obtains an Access Token and a Refresh Token successfully. All this OAUTH2 information is stored in the DefaultOAuth2ClientContext.

I can successfully request data using my provider's API, but after a few hours this OAUTH2 information dissapears from the context, and i am forced to restart the whole procedure (request a new Authorisation Code, obtain an Access Token, etc...). Is there a built-in mechanism that causes the context to be reset?

I am using Tomcat 7 and Java 1.7 JDK

Comment: Apparently, this issue is caused by the web-environment in which the OAuth2 application is used: The Auth2 information (access token, refresh token, ...) is stored in the context, but the context is not shared among different users because every user has his own session. Sessions are identified by tomcat using locally stored cookies. Disabling cookies is not a solution either because Tomcat will then initiate a new session every time, and only during the first attempt the user will be able to send a request and receive data successfully because the Authorisation Code can only be used once.

Comment: The following thread from Spring Forum is quite interesting for this problem: 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/oauth/117508-clienttokenservices